# Concat excel files and worksheets into one using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation

I have many excel files in a directory, all of them has the same header row. Some of these excel files has multiple worksheets which again have the same headers. I'm trying to loop through the excel files in the directory and for each one check if there are multiple worksheets to concat them as well as the rest of the excel files.

This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import ntpath
import glob

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(dir_path)

for excel_names in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    # read them in
    i=0
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_names[i], sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True)
    cdf = pd.concat(df.values())
    cdf.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
    excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

    # turn them into dataframes
    frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

    # delete the first row for all frames except the first
    # i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
    frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

    # concatenate them..
    combined = pd.concat(frames)

    # write it out
    combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
    i+=1
```

but then I get the below error any advice?

```
"concat excel.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_names[i], sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 350, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 653, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 424, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'G'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` statement is setting `excel_names` to each filename in turn (so a better variable name would be `excel_name`):

```
for excel_names in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
```

But inside the loop your code does

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_names[i], sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True)
```

where you are clearly expecting `excel_names` to be a list from which you are extracting one element. But it isn't a list, it's a string. So you are getting the first character of the first filename.